# Simple MySQL database questions - Database per user of application?

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

Currently I have developed an android application that uses a local sqlite database per installation.  The database comes pre-populated with static tables, and the entire point of the application is to allow the user to assign dates/comments with the pre-populated information in each table.

I am looking to bring this online, and move the database to a mysql format, allowing access via desktops and other mobile devices.  Is the best way to handle this to assign each new user a new database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly avoid creating multiple databases, and instead add relationships to the existing database structure you have with a users table. Each user has an association to each existing object. Keep in mind sharing with other users in the event that you may want to allow one user to see another user's info.

My suggestion is provide an update to the app where after the first launch after updating it pushes their information to your MySQL database and inform the users that they can access their data via other methods now.

Answer (score 3):

how many user to you expect? I would use only one database with a user table instead of hundreds/thousands of databases.

Answer (score 3):

One table for all users (only with user info like id, email, password, etc).

Another table with comments (with user id and his comment), so that you can add as many comments per user as needed. If dates are related to comments put them on this table, else another table for dates as well.